# How can i show form fields when click on p:command Link?

Tags: primefaces

Here is my code.

Show Fields when click on command Link.

Code for Fields:

```
<div class="col-md-12 Spacing" style="margin-top: 1%;">
<div class="col-md-3" style="padding-top: 7px;">
 <p:outputLabel styleClass="WhiteBlue" value="Ref#" /></div>            
<div class="col-md-9">              
<p:inputText type="text" styleClass="form-control" required="false" requiredMessage="required" value="#{pmBean.addpfmworkorderhead.refno}" id="refno" disabled="true"/>
</div>
</div>
```

Code for Link:

```
<p:commandLink oncomplete="PF('dlgwwv').show();"
                            action="#{pmController.createWorkOrderFromRca}" process="@this" update="AddNewEntryDialog:RcaDialog" id="rd">
    <h:graphicImage name="images/AttachDetails.gif" style="margin-left: 1%;"
    title="Create Work Order with reference to RCA" />
                        </p:commandLink>
```

Comment: And what is your problem?

Comment: And why are they not shown in the first place? And it does work using An `h:commandButton`with `f:ajax`?

Comment: @DavidStockinger I want to show fields when click on commandLink otherwise it's not visible to the user.

Comment: @Kukeltje Fields appear but I want to show fields when click on commandLink otherwise it's not visible to the user. I am not using h:commandButton.

Comment: So what did you try to initially hide them and show them based on an action? And you could **try** using an `h:commandButton` with `f:ajax` since if that fails to, the problem is most likely a pure jsf one and **not** PrimeFaces related!!!

Comment: @KukeltjeI am using rendered it hide the fields but when I click on command link it doesn't show the fields.